# How to produce a NaN in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, nan

In C, `math.h` defines `nan`. Is there a similar facility in Haskell whose only purpose is to produce a NaN?

Or is something like `0/0` or `acos(2)` my only choice?

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ClassyPrelude-0.1/docs/Prelude-Math.html <- I can see there is `isnan` defined there, but nothing to produce a NaN.

Comment: Although I agree the question is not the same, and it was correct of you to open two separate questions, the answer is the same, so it is correct of me to close this as a duplicate. =P