# How to produce infinity in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, infinity

Similarily to [How to produce a NaN in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902511/how-to-produce-a-nan-in-haskell) ...

In C, there is the `INFINITY` macro, defined by `math.h`.

Again, in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ClassyPrelude-0.1/docs/Prelude-Math.html I can see falicities to test for infnity, but not to produce one.

Therefore, is my only choice something like `1/0`?

Comment: _What's wrong with `last [0..]`?_

Comment: @leftaroundabout Infinite loop.

Comment: Actually that's not the only problem (`succ` just stops working in floating point, already around 1e16), but, you know what I was going at...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Tbh, I don't. Either this is some inside joke I'm not getting or some clever use of laziness I don't understand :(

Comment: @gaazkam It was a joke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`iee754`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754) package has functions and constants specific to that floating point format.

In particular, it has the `Numeric.IEEE.infinity` constant for members for the `IEEE` class (which float and double belong to). It is pretty much just implemented as `1/0` though, so your call if you want the package dependency for a prettier name.

Comment: `Numeric.Limits` also has these.